# "sudo" operations from python daemon

Tags: python, linux

I am writing a python administrative daemon on linux that needs to start/stop other services. Following the principle of least privilege, I want to run this normally with regular user privileges but when it needs to start/stop other services, I want it to become root. Essentially I want to do what sudo would do from the command line. I cannot directly exec sudo from the daemon because it has no tty. I want to avoid running the daemon as root when it does not need to run as root. Is there any way to do this from python without needing to use sudo?

Thank you in advance.

Ranga.

Comment: Create a new user just for that daemon and give the daemon user sudo permissions with no password required? Note that `sudo` provides different means of controlling which commands can be sudoed.

Comment: Tried that but it won't work. I cant exec sudo commands from the daemon because sudo requires a login shell to run.

Comment: I don't think sudo should help here, because if your application could unconditionally sudo without password, it is basically running with root rights. The way this usually is done, is to start the daemon as root but split it and spawn a new process with less privileges,  that does most of the work and only relays the requests, that require root rights to the parent process. The code for the parent process can be kept to a minimum with tight restrictions, therefore minimizing the attack surface. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation

Comment: I thought about it a bit and decided to separate my code into one small self contained piece that runs as root + everything else that runs unprivileged. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I have a flask back end that needed to do something privileged. I broke it up into two back ends - one unprivileged and another small privileged piece rather than use sudo.

It is also possible to run sudo in a pty but I decided against this approach as it does indeed have a security flaw.